# Cucumber no match gherkin in French if sentence contain apostrophe

Tags: java, cucumber, cucumber-jvm, gherkin

I use Cucumber-jvm 4.x.x with new syntaxe ([official doc here](https://docs.cucumber.io/cucumber/cucumber-expressions/))

i have a apostrophe between `d` and `écran` so gherkin sentence do not match with my java (Cucumber)

```
@Et("Je sauvegarde une capture d'écran dans {string}")
```

My Gherkin file is:

```
# language: fr
@bonjour
Fonctionnalité: bonjour (Fonction pour valider l environnement.) 

Plan du Scénario: Function to validate the environment.
  Et Je sauvegarde une capture d'écran dans 'myScreenshot-<id>'
Exemples:
    #DATA
    |id|author|zip|city|element|element2|date|title|
    |1|Jenkins T1|35000|Rennes|smile|smile|16/01/2020||
    |2|Jenkins T2|75000|Paris|smile|smile|||
    #END
```

I have this error:

```
cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: io.cucumber.cucumberexpressions.CucumberExpressionException: Parameter types cannot be alternative: Je sauvegarde une capture d'écran dans {string}
```

**EDIT:**

If i try this, I have the same error:

```
 @Et("Je sauvegarde une capture d\'écran dans {string}")
```

Comment: what value are you passing in for `{string}`?

Comment: Gerkin: Et Je sauvegarde une capture d'écran dans 'myScreenshot-<id>'

Comment: Was this working in version 3?

Comment: I can't reproduce this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
@Et("Je sauvegarde une capture d\'écran dans {string}")
```

A backslash is the regex escape character.

Comment: Post the entire step definition, S'il vous plaît.

Comment: Gherkin sentance: Et Je sauvegarde une capture d'écran dans 'myScreenshot-<id>'